# How to open the asset upload window when a user click on property in the styleManager in grapesjs

Tags: grapesjs

I'm in the process of developing a new plugin to introduce a "Background Video" option in grapesjs. I've successfully added a new property named 'Background Video' to the Style Manager's Decorations section. Now, I would like to enhance the user experience by opening the asset upload window whenever a user clicks on the 'Background Video' property.

Could you please guide me on how to achieve this functionality? Your assistance is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your help!